# Can Ant repackage classes at buildtime?

Tags: java, reflection, ant, build, software-packaging

Are there any Ant tasks (basic Ant or plugins alike), or Java that I could execute from inside an Ant target (with `<java/>` task), that would allow me to repackage all of my `com.myorg.slf4j.**` types to a new package called `org.slf4j.impl`?

Hence, post-build, `com.myorg.slf4j.LoggerFactory` is now repackaged to `org.slf4j.impl.LoggerFactory`, etc. Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Google found the following:

- http://gslsrc.net/l005_repackaging_java_project_using_ant.html
- http://www.retrologic.com/rg-docs-repackage.html
- [How to repackage .class files from the default package using jarjar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182273/how-to-repackage-class-files-from-the-default-package-using-jarjar)

Hope that helps.