# Can't access .jar file within IntelliJ after adding it

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

So I've set up my IntelliJ 14 with .jar files I want to use in the following screenshot:
[image]

You can see that I can import code from the `mnist-tools.jar` file but when I try to import the HeapTracker file in `heapTracker.jar` IntelliJ isn't recognizing it. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Is the use of Java's default package a bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849421/is-the-use-of-javas-default-package-a-bad-practice) and [How to import a class from default package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193226/how-to-import-a-class-from-default-package). Short answer, it's not possible; Long answer is it's messy and should just be avoided

Answer (score 2):

You can't import classes from the default package. You want the file in the jar to be in a specific package.

From the JLS [7.5.1. Single-Type-Import Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1):

> The name must be qualified ([§6.5.5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.5.2)), or a compile-time error occurs.