# Why do I need to put a Java class in a package?

Tags: java, class, package, warnings

I was wondering why Java tells you it is not recommended to create classes in the default package.

Is is for organization purposes? Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Alternative answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849421/is-the-use-of-javas-default-package-a-bad-practice).