# Intellij, cannot resolve symbol ByteBufferGuard

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import

I have setup a small [project](https://github.com/elect86/unofficial-opengl-SDK/tree/master/src/main/java), with a small final class `ByteBufferGuard` in a `ByteBufferGuard.java` file:

```
final class ByteBufferGuard {
    @FunctionalInterface
    static interface BufferCleaner {
        void freeBuffer(String resourceDescription, ByteBuffer b) throws IOException;
    }
}
```

And then another class, `MMapDirectory.java`. Well, in this class I can't refer to `BufferCleaner` simply by importing it, because this:

`import ByteBufferGuard.BufferCleaner;`

returns:

> cannot resolve symbol ByteBufferGuard

But it's strange because only `ByteBufferGuard` is marked red, it does see, instead, what comes next, that is `BufferCleaner`.

Both classes are located under the same gradle default root package, that is `src/main/java/`

Looking at similar answers, I already tried to "invalidate caches/restart" and also delete `.idea` folder and open the project again.. no success so far.

Let's say this is not a blocker, because I can substitute all the references of `BufferCleaner` with `ByteBufferGuard.BufferCleaner`, but still it bothers me, so I'd like to solve this issue.

Do you know what could be the problem?

java 1.8 u112

intellij 2017.1 eap

Another interesting fact, is that the very same import using Kotlin works like a charm..

Comment: Make `ByteBufferGuard` `public`?

Comment: I think you need to import the whole class: `import ByteBufferGuard`. Not 100% sure.

Comment: @CKing, they are under the same package so it shouldn't matter, however I tried to write `public final class ByteBufferGuard` but unfortunately it doesn't work neither

Comment: @YogevLevy, when I type `import ByteBufferGuard`, `ByteBufferGuard` is red.

Comment: Try `import static ByteBufferGuard.BufferCleaner;`? Also, is `MMapDirectory.java` in the same package as `ByteBufferGuard`?

Comment: @CKing, tried, exactly same result, `ByteBufferGuard` red, but `.BufferCleaner` not. Yes, they are under the same package

Comment: Weird. You are not giving us the right information then.

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask me whatever you think it might be the right information, then :)

Comment: You might want to try to copy/paste those two classes and try out yourself. I am curious to know if it works on your machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the `default package` (unnamed package) - if you move both files to a package (subdirectory) it should work.

```
package some.package;

final class ByteBufferGuard {
    @FunctionalInterface
    static interface BufferCleaner {
        void freeBuffer(String resourceDescription, ByteBuffer b) throws IOException;
    }
}
```

and

```
package some.package;

import some.package.ByteBufferGuard.BufferCleaner;

public class MapDirectory {
    private BufferCleaner cleaner;
    // ...
}
```

(tested with eclipse, but should be the same)

It is not possible to import classes from the `default package`:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7849460/85421
- [How to import a class from default package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193226/how-to-import-a-class-from-default-package)

Comment: downvote without comment will not help improve the answer!

Comment: It was indeed this the problem, thanks Carlos!

Comment: I +1 (when it was 0), and it's zero again, it looks like someone else also downvoted.. I won't never understand those people..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make your class `public`, or if You want to be a package, make sure, other `class` who use `ByteBufferGuard` is in the same package