# Can't export Clojure function from root file level

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

I have a Clojure project I created with `lein new`.  My Clojure files are all within a `src` folder, and all seem to be compiled when I run `lein uberjar` (I see errors in them when things are missing).

Within `src`, I have a folder `myns` with `junk.clj` in it.  That file has

```
(ns myns.junk)

(defn sq [x] (* x x))
```

After loading the jar created by lein uberjar in my java project, I can import and call that function via

```
import myns.junk$sq;

public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(junk$sq.invokeStatic(5));       
    }  
}
```

But I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to import functions from files that are *not* in a folder. Top-level files in my src folder seem invisible and unable to be imported on the Java side.

How do I tell Clojure to put similar functions in top-level files into some namespace that Java can import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single-segment namespaces (ie, `(ns myns)`) are strongly discouraged for exactly the reason that you have observed. They lead to classes with the name `myns$foo`, in the default package. The default package is super weird in a lot of ways, and Java developers never use it except for the tiniest of hello world programs. In particular, you cannot import a class from the default package, because there is no package name to import it from.

See [Is the use of Java's default package a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849421/is-the-use-of-javas-default-package-a-bad-practice) for more examples of reasons it is bad to use the default package; and because single-segment namespaces in Clojure are implemented by putting classes into the default package, this implies you also should not use single-segment namespaces.