# Why in the official Kotlin coding conventions we should omit root package in directory structure?

Tags: kotlin, coding-style

In the official Kotlin coding conventions (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html) they recommend to us to omit root package in directory structure. It is not comfortable, when you create a new file in your `kotlin` source folder and then edit the package name, because it did not generated automatically.

Comment: Recent versions of the Kotlin plugin (starting from 1.2.20 I think) do generate the package name when you create new Kotlin files in the root folder, if all other files in that folder have the same package declaration.

Answer (score 4):

From a [Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7mwopn/new_official_kotlin_style_guide/ds80nnl/):

> I guess you're supposed to use the package prefix
>   [image]
>    in the project structure, but sadly that feature is only available in IDEA and not Android Studio.

I agree it's weird that it's not documented more explicitly, I've only found https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html. You may want to consider raising the issue on http://discuss.kotlinlang.org/.

Comment: Thanks for information about package prefix! But is there some explanation why do we need omit the root package directory? Why is it good for project source code?  I heard about one advantage: refactoring root package does not move files from one directory to another - but I dont think that it is advantage

Comment: I don't think there is any "need", it's just to get a simpler and easier-to-navigate directory structure with no disadvantages once you set package prefix (unless you use tools assuming complete correspondence between directory and package structure and which can't be taught this difference).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov But how can I set the package prefix by using build tools (e.g. Gradle)? Because once I refreshed my gradle project, the package prefix got reset.

Comment: @Sola I don't know. You may want to make it a separate question here or at https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like support for `packagePrefix` was added to `idea-ext` gradle plugin in version 0.5 : https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin/wiki/DSL-spec-v.-0.5#package-prefix-requires-idea-20191

Comment: Cool! Thanks for info

Answer (score -3):

I think this rule is inherited from Java code style where using of default package is a bad practice.

You can check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849421/is-the-use-of-javas-default-package-a-bad-practice) to obtain more information about default package in Java.

Comment: Yes, defualt package is a bad practice, but in case of Koltin coding conventions, they did not recommend use defualt package, they recommend omit root package in directory structure and define package directive in your source code files like root package is exists

Comment: Yes, this has absolutely nothing to do with default package.