# Maven - Project classes not recognized in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am new to Maven and working in intellij

What I did

1. Create new maven project
2. Copy in my directory of java files from a previous project
3. edit my POM for all dependencies

Intelij says it can not find my project classes when I call them from other files. (See Picture)

I have tried a re-build and clean but I can not use my project classes. Alt-Enter does not show any hope.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the picture, Node class is in the default package and Sample class in sample package.

Try putting Node in a package and import it in Sample class.

Just as a reminder the [usage of default package is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7849460/520275).