# Imported jar is visible in default package but not in others

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a jar called `MyMathsJar`.

I added it in the build path.

I can access to its content in the default package of my current project and it is working fine.

```
MyMaths m = new MyMaths();
System.out.println(m.addition(1, 3));
```

However, if I want to do the same thing in the package `customerPack` in my current project it is not working. I got this error :

> MyMaths can not be resolved as a type.

Someone can explain me why please? Thank you.

Comment: Is the class you are attempting to use also in a default package?

Comment: Don't use the default package. You can only ever access classes in the default package from code that is *also* in the default package.

Comment: Yes it is in the default package.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thank you. Do you know the reason of this behavior?

Comment: @Royce: using the default package is prone to naming conflicts, so it's basically not supported for anything but the smallest sample programs. See [this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849421/is-the-use-of-javas-default-package-a-bad-practice).

Comment: [How to access java-classes in the default-package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/283816/85421) or [How to import a class from default package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2193226/85421)

Comment: It's a good reason ahah. Thank you.